# Error with JLists in a GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jscrollpane, jlist

I needed to add two JLists into a JScrollPane, so i added the two JLists into a JPanel and I set the JPanel as the viewport view of the JScrollPane.

Now, the problem is that I want to make the two JLists seem like one, and I don't know which Layout choose.

I've tried with GridBagLayout, but the result is that

GridBagLayout:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDSQf.png]

I've also tried with BoxLayout, but i got this:

BoxLayout:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLuNl.png]

Is there any way to fix the problem?

Comment: `Now, the problem is that I want to make the two JLists seem like one` - so just make one JList. `Is there any way to fix the problem?` - what problem? What are you expecting to see?

Comment: I need to change the background of the element of a JList depending on what's written inside the element. In the BoxLayout the two elements should have the same widht of the jpanel

Comment: How does having two JLists help with this. It looks like you are creating a chat application. So how do you see the flow of the conversation. Once the first JList has 10 items you won't even see the text of the second JList. So again, why are you creating two JLists? If you want a different color background for a different person in the chat then you store an Object in the JList which has two pieces of information, "id", "text". Then you create a custom renderer for the JList. You display the text and then set the background based on the ID.

Comment: I'm creating a chat application, and in this panel i want to show the list of the online users in this moment. Please camickr can you make me some code example of the custom renderer?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any suggestions, because I don't understand your requirement of having two lists look like one. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Writing a Custom Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for some basics. You can then search the forum/web for more examples.

Comment: Thank You camickr